# Getting error in PHP 5.3 which works in php 5.4

Tags: php

Here is the line which gave me error in PHP 5.3 which runs perfectly in php 5.4

```
if ($user->getGeoCode()) { 
    $latitude = $user->getGeoCode()['latitude'];
}
```

The error message is :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in IndexController.php on line 29
```

Here is my user class:

```
 class User {
   .....
  public function getGeoCode() {
    $geoCode=array();
    if ($this->getAddress() && $this->getCity() && $this->getCountry()) {
        $address = urlencode($this->getAddress() . ' ' . $this->getCity() . ' ' . $this->getPostalCode() . ' ' . $this->getCountry()->getName());
        $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false');
        $output = json_decode($geocode);
        if ($output->status=='OK') {
            $geoCode['latitude']=$output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
            $geoCode['longitude']=$output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            return $geoCode;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
     }
     else {
        return null;
     }
   }
 }
```

Is this error related to version of PHP ?

Comment: can you please print the value of $user->getGeoCode();

Comment: what if you surround in brackets your call? **($user->getGeoCode())['latitude']**. You could also try an assegnation: $tmp=$user->getGeoCode(); $latitude=$tmp[];

Answer (score 3):

Error message explains everything. PHP5.3 doesn't support casting function output automatically to array and accessing it like this.

Since PHP 5.4 it's possible to do exactly that [Example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88)

Prior to PHP 5.3, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

**EDIT**

by `casting` I ment `dereferencing`.

Comment: This isn't about casting the return value of a function, but about being able to dereference the array directly on the function-call. +1 non the less, for pointing to the right section of the docs.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not very good in english and sometimes I say it wrong.

Comment: This is more jargon than English. Still, no need to apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is realated to php version.

This is because php 5.3 interpreter, doesn't accept a sytnax like  `$user->getGeoCode()['latitude']`

while php 5.4 interpreter does.

Answer (score 2):

In the [PHP documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you can find the explanation:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

Comment: +1 for linking the error to 'array dereferencing' in docs.

Answer (score 2):

As [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) says:

PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features:

- Support for traits has been added.
- Short array syntax has been added, e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.
- **Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].**
- Closures now support $this.
- < ?= is now always available, regardless of the short_open_tag php.ini option.
- Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().
- Class::{expr}() syntax is now supported.
- Binary number format has been added, e.g. 0b001001101.
- Improved parse error messages and improved incompatible arguments warnings.
- The session extension can now track the upload progress of files.
- Built-in development web server in CLI mode.

Try this:

```
if ($geodata = $user->getGeoCode()) { 
    $latitude = $geodata['latitude'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because this is new feature of PHP 5.4.short hand array is not supported by 5.3